# How to read a new line or lines added in text file in java

Tags: java

I have been trying to use randomacess to read the new line but I am not able to get the file pointer of previous iteration stored and compare it with the end of line of the latest file and read just the difference.

Any help is appreciated.

```
    try {
        String data =fromNode+" "+message+" "+toNode;

        File fileTo = new File(File.separator + "Users" + File.separator
                + "Apoorv" + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator
                + "Files" + File.separator + "to" + toNode + ".txt");
        File fileFrom = new File(File.separator + "Users" + File.separator
                + "Apoorv" + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator
                + "Files" + File.separator + "from" + fromNode + ".txt");

        // if file does not exists, then create it
        if (!fileTo.exists()) {
            fileTo.createNewFile();
        }

        if (!fileFrom.exists()) {
            fileFrom.createNewFile();
        }

        // true = append file
        FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(fileTo, true);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
        bufferWritter.write(data);
        bufferWritter.newLine();
        bufferWritter.close();


        //logic to check whether there exist a link between the nodes
        for (int i=0;i< pairUniList.size() - 1; i++){   
        if(pairUniList.get(i).getX()==fromNode && pairUniList.get(i).getY()==toNode){
            //System.out.println("values: "+ pairList.get(i).getX()+"---"+fromNode+"---->"+pairList.get(i).getY()+"---"+toNode);
        FileWriter fileWritterfrom = new FileWriter(fileFrom,
                true);
        // System.out.println("------>"+data);
        BufferedWriter bufferWritterfrom = new BufferedWriter(
                fileWritterfrom);
        bufferWritterfrom.write(data);
        bufferWritterfrom.newLine();
        bufferWritterfrom.close();

        }
        }
        System.out.println("Files have been created");

        //trying to check for the end of line

        RandomAccessFile myFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileTo,"rw");

        // Set write pointer to the end of the file
        myFile.seek(myFile.length());
        System.out.println("***");

        // Write to end of file here

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ******************************************************************




}
```

## sample of code

Comment: I just want to read the new addition every second.

Comment: It will be good if you can show us some code which you have tried.

Comment: you might want to look into pipes http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/pipe.html

Comment: I have been trying to use seek command but as it doesnt return any value, I just need a workaround

Comment: @LorenzoBoccaccia I have to write a text file using some logic and that file is checked every second for new addition, if any then copy the content of new additon to other file using some logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
   try {

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(
                    File.separator + "Users" + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator
                + "Files" + File.separator + "from" + fromNode + ".txt");

            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String line;

            while (true) {

                line = br.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } else {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

This solves my problem of reading the new line every second.